# Правильно ли отображается реклама?

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сбилдил игру в юнити, установил на телефон. Когда начинаю смотреть рекламу, то там каждый раз показывается один и тот же ролик (от Unity Ads). Может быть после релиза на площадках должна реклама начать показываться или как?

Comment: `Unity Ads` не особенный, у всех есть тестоая и реальная реклама.

Answer (score 5):

В Unity Dashboard имеется галочка "Ad Test Mode", ее нужно снять чтобы показывалась не тестовая реклама.
Также этот параметр можно отключить в самой юнити на вкладке Services.

> Navigate to the target project on Ads Dashboard: https://operate.dashboard.unity3d.com
> Select Platforms on the left sidebar under the Monetization section, choose your platform
> Click Settings tab. Scroll down to TEST MODE section, turn ON override client test mode, click Force Test Mode OFF and Save

https://answers.unity.com/questions/1301988/turning-off-unity-ads-test-mode-without-redeployin.html